# Scrollbar in Listbox not working

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollbar

I have a `ListBox` that displays a list of WPF controls.
My problem is that the vertical scrollbar is show but is disabled even when there are enough items that the `ListBox` should be scrollable.
One other possibly relevant fact is that this is contained in an `Integration.ElementHost`.

WPF noobie, Jim

Here is the XAML for the `ListBox`:

```
  // for brevity I removed the Margin and Tooltip attributes

  <Grid x:Class="Xyzzy.NoteListDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Name="AllRecent" IsChecked="False" >View All Recent</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Name="AscendingOrder" IsChecked="False">Descending Order</CheckBox>
            <Button Name="btnTextCopy" Click="btnCopyText_Click">Copy All</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="NoteList"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        </ListBox>
      </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

And the XAML for the control displayed in each `ListBox` item:

```
  <UserControl x:Class="Xyzzy.NoteDisplay"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Name="Heading" FontSize="10">Note Heading</TextBlock>
          <Button Name="btnCopyText" Height="20" FontSize="12"
                          Click="btnCopyText_Click">Copy
          </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="Body" FontSize="14">Note Body</TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have had problems with scroll bar visibility when using a `StackPanel`.  I think it is because the `StackPanel` is always as big as it needs to be to contain all of its children.  Try reorganizing the layout to remove the `StackPanel` (use a `Grid` instead) and see if that helps.

Comment: When I put Listbox into Grid rather than StackPanel the problem disapeared.

I this a WPF code bug, WPF design bug or deliberate WPF behavior??

Comment: I think it is just the way the StackPanel works.  In your case the StackPanel was as tall as the ListBox needed to be without scrolling, then the StackPanel got "cut off" at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with StackPanel and the issue get resolved by Grid. Thanks @JohnMyczek

Comment: Ideed - I had the same problem and I solved it by managing to remove the stackpanel

Comment: If the grid solution does not work at once, set `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` for the row containing the ListBox.

Comment: Are you freak'n kidding me??  I just spent 5 hours trying to figure out why my listbox wasn't behaving and this was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You just need to introduce **`Height`** property, like this:

```
<ListBox Height="200" 
         Name="NoteList"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Confirmed this solution works with a StackPanel, despite the accepted answer mentioning otherwise. Also the "Visible" can be changed to "Auto" so you only get a scroll bar when needed. And Height can be changed to MinHeight.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - Hard coding the height only works as long as you can not resize anything. As soon as someone resizes the window, this fails. You need to do it in a way that automatically resizes.

Answer (score 4):

Heya, I suspect what might be happening is that your ListBox is expanding enough for every item however the ListBox is actually disappearing off the bottom of the Containing Control.

Does the ListBox actually stop properly or does it just seem to disappear? Try setting a MaxHeight on the ListBox and see if that makes the scrollbar appear. You should be able to set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto to have it only appear when needed.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried restricting the size of the Listbox exactly as you suggest.  The result was no improvement.

Comment: Rach was right in my case. The control just expanded unbound and just disappeared beyond my control bounds. I used to have the ListBox in a grid row/column with Width/Height set to Auto. Once these were set to '*' the ListBox started to behave.

Answer (score 2):

If the list box is inside a StackPanel, try these steps for your ListBox

1. Set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
2. Setting the Height property of a ListBox  to some height that you expect to see.

That should force the scroll bar to show up.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty late, but anyone using ListBox probably shouldn't have it in a StackPanel. Once I switched the parent control of my Listbox from StackPanel to DockPanel with LastChildFill=True (Where the listbox was the last control), my scrollbar worked perfectly.

Hope this helps someone who's problem was not solved by the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem that works well is to put a `ScrollViewer` around the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a modification to Dave's is to use the ScrollViewer only.  You only be able to scroll by placing your mouse on the ScrollView's ScrollBar.  I use it this way because I don't like how ListBox jumps from item to item and sometimes missing items from the Top.  Little bit hard on the eyes too.  I like ScrollViewer's smooth scrolling.

Comment: Just read this post to add scrolling when the mouse is over the ListBox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976240/how-can-make-scrollviewer-scroll-when-mouse-is-over-any-content?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, and here's a little code demo on code project that visually shows it.

(If you want to save yourself the time of writing the code to see the differences yourself :) )

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659066/ListBox-and-Panels-in-WPF