# How can make ScrollViewer scroll when mouse is over *any* content

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

The reason I stress 'any' is because `CanContentScroll` is not fully working in my `ScollViewer`.
Let me explain the scenario:
I have a `ScrollViewer` that has three Labels followed by a `ListBox` each. The reason I have this content inside the `ScrollViewer` is because I don't want each `ListBox` to have a `ScrollBar`, I just want one "global" `ScrollBar`. The problem is that when the cursor is over the the `ListBox` the `ScrollViewer` doesn't scroll. I've tried to set `CanContentScroll` property to true in the ScrollViewer, the ListBox and on the ListBoxItem style, without success. Is there other Control type I should use?
Here is my code sample:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Telbit.TeStudio.View.Controls.TestStepsView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Telbit.TeStudio.View.Controls">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:TestStepsStepViewModel}">
        <my:TestStepsStepView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="StepItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#40a0f5ff"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF2F2F2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Gainsboro" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</UserControl.Background>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <HeaderedContentControl Grid.Row="0" >
        <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
            <Grid Background="#e8f2f8">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200" Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="#" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="2 2 0 2"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Content="Folder\Name" 
                       BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Type" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="Auto Start" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Run After" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="5" Content="Stop After" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="6" Content="Delay (s)" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="7" Content="Timestamp" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 0 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="8" Content="Edited by" BorderBrush="#70add4" BorderThickness="0 2 2 2" Margin="-20 0 0 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanContentScroll="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Name="lblSetup" Grid.Row="0" 
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                   BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                   TextBlock.FontSize="10pt" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.Foreground="#949494"
                   Content="Setup" AllowDrop="True"/>
            <ListBox Name="itmCtrlSetupSteps" Grid.Row="1"
                     BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SetupSteps}" SelectionMode="Single"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StepItemStyle}"
                     SelectionChanged="manageStep_SelectionChanged"
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                     />

            <Label Name="lblTest" Grid.Row="2" 
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                   BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                   TextBlock.FontSize="10pt" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.Foreground="#949494"
                   Content="Test" AllowDrop="True"/>
            <ListBox Name="itmCtrlTestSteps" Grid.Row="3"
                     BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding TestSteps}" SelectionMode="Single"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StepItemStyle}"
                     SelectionChanged="manageStep_SelectionChanged"
                     />

            <Label Name="lblTearDown" Grid.Row="4" 
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                   BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                   TextBlock.FontSize="10pt" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" TextBlock.Foreground="#949494"
                   Content="Tear Down" AllowDrop="True"/>
            <ListBox Name="itmCtrlTearDownSteps" Grid.Row="5"
                     BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding TearDownSteps}" SelectionMode="Single"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StepItemStyle}"
                     SelectionChanged="manageStep_SelectionChanged"
                     />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that even though child list boxen don't have scroll bars visible, they do have `ScrollViewer` in them according to their template. Fortunately this template is easily modifiable. Do this for each child list box, or better yet put it in common style:

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

The default is almost the same with the exception of `ScrollViewer` wrapping around `ItemsPresenter`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want one `ScrollViewer` per `ListBox` (I have 3). I want one 'global' `ScrollViewer` that gives the feeling of a unique `ListBox`. From what I understood your code will give me one `ScrollViewer` per `ListBox`, right?

Comment: No, there's no ScrollViewer in my code. That's the whole point. Apply this to children to get rid of scrolling in them.

Comment: Sorry to doubt you, I should have tried the solution first..
It's working, thank you very much!